# What year to use copyright - current year or library build year?

Tags: copyright, license

When attributing open source software, do you always default to the current year or the year that the library you are using was built?

For example, I'm using MIT licensed software from a build in 2018, would I include 2018 in the copyright since that it is when it is built or 2019 as the author still asserts their copyright in 2019?

Answer (score 4):

Do not invent your own copyright notices, just use the one displayed by the software in question. This would typically be what you refer to as the “build year”.

When writing a copyright notice, the year should be the *year of publication* for this version – neither the current year, nor the year of writing. For some aspects of copyright, the year of first publication is relevant to calculate the copyright term. In most jurisdictions, copyright notices no longer have substantial legal relevance and could also be omitted. (But you may not falsify or remove them!)